# let Opera Mini (in Microemulator, on OS X) hit local network

Tags: networking, mac-osx, emulation, emulator

I just set up Microemulator on OS X (Leopard) and am running Opera Mini 4.2, hoping to test a mobile website I'm developing.

Opera Mini can hit public websites, but it can't to hit my test sites on OS X's Apache instance. I've tried:

- localhost/~myUserName/site (times
  out)
- myIpAddress/~myUserName/site
  (times out)
- myMachineName/~myUserName/site
  ("Address not available from this
  machine")

All of the above work for any OS X desktop browsers and for Windows VMs that I test with.

[Microemulator's network config options](http://www.microemu.org/faq.html#proxy) appear to be limited to setting a proxy server:

```
<system-properties>
     <system-property name="http.proxyHost" value="webcache.mydomain.com"></system-property>
     <system-property name="http.proxyPort" value="8080"></system-property>
     <system-property name="http.nonProxyHosts" value="localhost"></system-property>
</system-properties>
```

I'm not sure if setting these can help me or not... seems like I need to be able to set DNS for Microemulator, not necessarily a proxy server.

Any suggestions on how/if I might get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot - by the very definition of opera mini - it will not work.

om uses intermediary proxy hosted by opera, this proxy establishes connection to the website, parses its content and sends you back digasted output in a proprietary format. so your test website needs to be reachable for the opera mini proxies - it needs to be internet reachable.

solution: set reverse proxy/port forward so your local http server can be reached from the internet.

Comment: or perhaps Opera Mobile would work instead?

Comment: Well, duh. I actually knew Opera Mini worked like that at one point and it had completely slipped my mind, or just got mixed it up with Opera Mobile, which appears to be the more "traditional" type browser.

Comment: @Chris_K -- I don't think one is really a good substitue for the other for development/testing. The rendering may be the same but the basic functionality between Opera Mini & Opera Mobile is pretty different. http://www.opera.com/products/choose/  Thanks, though.

Comment: @Chris_k - right. opera mobile is fully-blown web browser and it works fine with local / intranet servers.